# Mapping a set of boolean columns to non-fixed columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

| id | reason1 | reason2 | reason3 | reason4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

```
df <- as.dataframe('id' = c(1, 2, 3), 'reason1' = c(0, 0, 0), 'reason2' = c(1, 0, 0), 'reason3' = c(1, 0, 0), 'reason4' = c(0, 1, 1))
```

Here if
`reason1` = `Rain` if 1
`reason2` = `Wind` if 1
`reason3` = `Thunder` if 1
`reason4` = `None` if 1

Now I want these columns to be mapped to new set of columns named `condition`. Irrespective of order of reason columns filled in (e.g. `reason2` & `reason3` or `reason3` &`reason4`), I want both of them to be mapped to `condition` and `condition2` columns. My final dataframe should look like below,

| id | condition | condition2 | condition3 | condition4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Wind | Thunder | NA | NA |
| 2 | None | NA | NA | NA |
| 3 | None | NA | NA | NA |

```
df_new <- as.dataframe('id' = c(1, 2, 3), 'condition' = c('Wind', 'None', 'None), 'condition2' = c('Thunder', NA, NA), 'condition3' = c(NA, NA, NA), 'condition4' = c(NA, NA, NA))
```

How to obtain this in R?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `base R` vectorized way using `which`:

```r
reasons <- c("Rain", "Wind", "Thunder", "None")

#Which of the elements are 1
w <- which(df[-1] == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)

#Create new empty data.frame
df2 <- df; df2[-1] <- NA; colnames(df2)[-1] <- paste0("condition", 1:4)

#Fill data.frame
df2[cbind(w[, 1], sequence(rle(w[, 1])$lengths) + 1)] <- reasons[w[, 2]]

#   id condition1 condition2 condition3 condition4
# 1  1       Wind    Thunder         NA         NA
# 2  2       None       <NA>         NA         NA
# 3  3       None       <NA>         NA         NA
```

---

Or a non-vectorized way with `apply`:

```r
df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, \(x){
  v <- reasons[which(x == 1)]
  x <- ifelse(seq_along(x) %in% seq(length(v)), v, NA)
  x
}))
```

Comment: Your code works perfect! But can you provide the code using tidyverse?

Comment: @Onyambu's answer is the way to go in tidyverse

Answer (score 1):

in Base R use :

```
cbind(df[1],stack(df, -id))|>
    subset(values > 0) |>
    transform(conditions = reasons[ind], row.names = NULL, ind = NULL,
                        values = NULL,time = ave(id, id, FUN=seq_along))|>
    reshape(v.names = 'conditions', dir='wide', sep='')

  id conditions1 conditions2
1  1        Wind     Thunder
3  2        None        <NA>
4  3        None        <NA>
```

---

If using `tidyverse`-same logic:

```
df %>%
    pivot_longer(-id) %>%
    filter(value>0) %>%
    mutate(value = reasons[parse_number(name)], name = row_number(), .by = id) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_prefix = 'conditions')

# A tibble: 3 × 3
     id conditions1 conditions2
  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>      
1     1 Wind        Thunder    
2     2 None        NA         
3     3 None        NA
```

Comment: value = reasons[parse_number(name)], name = row_number(), .by = id, can you check this line?

Comment: @learner What about the line?

Comment: the code doesn't gives the output as expected. For id 2 and 3, None is in conditions3 and conditions 4 respectively. But my request is different.

Comment: @learner I do not understand what you mean. `None` is in `conditions1` as given in the final results above. Although previously in reason4, they were moved to condition1

Comment: this is the dataframe i get df <- data.frame(
  'id' = c(1, 2, 3),
  'conditions1' = c('Wind', NA, NA),
  'conditions2' = c('Thunder', NA, NA),
  'conditions3' = c(NA, 'None', NA),
  'conditions4' = c(NA, NA, 'None')
)

Comment: @learner what is your `name` variable values after the mutate? should be 1,2,1,1. Check whether thats the case. If you are getting 1,2,3,4 then thats means you are using an older version of tidyverse which does not take into consideration the `.by` argument. To solve the issue use `...%>%group_by(id) %>%mutate....`